# Can 오합지졸 describe the Halloween Crowd in Itaewon, South Korea?

Tags: vocabulary, hanja, examples

```
오합지졸
 - 까마귀 烏, 합합 合, 같지 之, 군사 卒
 - 아무 규율도 통일도 없이 몰려다니는 무리
 - A crowd that rushes around without any discipline or unity
```

Can the crowd from the 2022 Halloween tragedy in Itaewon be said to be an oh-hap-jee-johl?

Can this vocabulary phrase be used in an example sentence like this?

> 이태원에 있는 오합지졸 안에서 많은 정년이 목숨을 잃었습니다.

Answer (score 7):

No, 오합지졸 would be very inappropriate and offensive.

오합지졸 describes a group of people (e.g., soldiers, sports team, or school kids) who are tasked with something, but they're so incompetent and disorganized that they can't get anything done.  Some examples from news articles:

> GS칼텍스가 **'오합지졸'** 조직력으로 자멸한 IBK기업은행을 완파하고 새 시즌 V리그 첫 승을 신고했다.
>
> "푸틴은 진짜 멍청이"…러시아군, 우크라 침공 초기부터 **오합지졸**이었다
>
> 지금과 같은 모습으로는 민주당이 아무리 200석 이상을 받는다해도 **'오합지졸'인** 모습에서 절대 벗어날 수 없을 것이며 ...

So, if we use 오합지졸 to describe the Itaewon crowd, it would mean something like "Geez they couldn't even *walk* correctly without trampling themselves to death, what a bunch of idiots!"

Instead, a more appropriate expression is **아비규환** (originally a Buddhist term describing people suffering in hell) - it could roughly translate to "hell on earth."  One can easily find many news articles using this term to describe the Itaewon tragedy:

> 30일 새벽 서울 용산구 이태원동 도로는 **아비규환**이었다.
>
> [속보] 핼러윈 10만인파 몰린 이태원…압사사고로 **'아비규환'**